# Is this function tail recursive or not?

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion

The sum_aux function is (obviously) a tail recursive function. Is sum also a tail recursive function? It does nothing more than call sum_aux once.

Otherwise, I understand why sum_aux is tail recursive so no explanation needed for that.

```java
sum_aux(n,i,k) {
  if( i <= n ) {
    return sum_aux(n,i+1,k+i);
  } else {
    return k;
  }
}

sum(n) {
  return sum_aux(n,1,0);
}
```

Comment: A [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) doesn't have to be recursive - `sum_aux` is tail-recursive but `sum` uses just a tail call. Neither procedure grows the stack.

Answer (score 0):

No `sum` is not tail recursive, as `sum` is not *recursive*. It just happens to call a recursive function.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function):

> Recursive function (programming), a procedure or subroutine that references itself

`sum` does not call or references itself, therefor it is not recursive and thus also not tail recursive.

Comment: _"In computer science, a tail call is a subroutine call performed as the final action of a procedure.[1] If a tail call might lead to the same subroutine being called again later in the call chain, the subroutine is said to be tail-recursive, which is a special case of recursion."_ Not all tail calls are recursive ones. `sum` calls `sum_aux` in tail position, so it's still considered a tail call.

Comment: I just answered the question "Is sum also a *tail recursive* function?" (emphasis mine)